# How to align name and messagess

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to align badge , username and message for streamlabs chat.
currently have made this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrP1Z.png ,
but want it to look like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOXBG.png

so here is html and css not sure what im missing here but hope someone can help me with this

also if somebody does not have badges want his name to start from left without gaps which currently works with this setup.

```
<!-- chat item -->
<script type="text/template" id="chatlist_item">
  <div data-from="{from}" data-id="{messageId}">
    <span class="meta" style="color: {color}">
      <span class="badges"></span>
      <span class="name">{from}</span>
      <span class="message">{message}</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</script>
```

---

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700);

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000, 0 0 2px #000;
    background: {background_color};
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: {font_size};
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: {text_color};
}

#log>div {
    animation: fadeInRight .3s ease forwards, fadeOut 0.5s ease {message_hide_delay} forwards;
    -webkit-animation: fadeInRight .3s ease forwards, fadeOut 0.5s ease {message_hide_delay} forwards;
}

.colon {
    display: none;
}

#log {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 10px 10px;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

#log>div {
    display: table-row;
}

#log>div.deleted {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#log .emote {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    padding: 0.4em 0.2em;
    position: relative;
}

#log .emote img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1em;
    opacity: 0;
}

#log .message,#log .meta {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: table-cell;
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
    margin-left: 0.2em;
}

#log .meta {
    width: 35%;
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: clip;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#log .message {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: initial;
    width: 65%;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
}

.badge {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0.2em;
    position: relative;
    height: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    top: -0.1em;
}

.name {
    margin-left: 0.2em;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to wrap the class ".message" inside class ".name". Like this : 
<span class="name">{from} <span class="message">{message}</span></span>

Comment: yeah that doesnt change anything in this case

Comment: Can you try replacing "inline-block" with inline or just removing display property since span is already inline

Comment: @AlvinZachariah wow that did the trick thank you

Comment: Okay Ill add that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `display : inline-block` should do the trick . Inline-block create block elements without line breakers . In this case badges , name and messages are separate block elements positioned next to each other . Each element will still have its own boundaries and properties like margin can be applied to each of them .

Since your requirement is to display them as inline , either change `inline-block` to 'inline' or remove the `inline-block` as span in already an inline element

Comment: in this case changing display to inline did the trick, but removing display would show it as display:block; so just doing inline worked.